# How to save each line of a file to a new file (every line a new file) and do that for multiple original files

Tags: python, loops, line

I have 5 files from which i want to take each line (24 lines in total) and save it to a new file. I managed to find a code which will do that but they way it is, every time i have to manually change the number of the appropriate original file and of the file i want to save it to and also the number of each line every time.

The code:

```
x1= np.loadtxt("x_p2_40.txt")
x2= np.loadtxt("x_p4_40.txt")
x3= np.loadtxt("x_p6_40.txt")
x4= np.loadtxt("x_p8_40.txt")
x5= np.loadtxt("x_p1_40.txt")    

with open("x_p1_40.txt", "r") as file:
 content = file.read()
 first_line = content.split('\n', 1)[0]
with open("1_p_40_x.txt", "a" ) as f : 
       f.write("\n")
with open("1_p_40_x.txt", "a" ) as fa :     
       fa.write(first_line)
        
print(first_line)
```

I am a beginner at python, and i'm not sure how to make a loop for this, because i assume i need a loop?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do - What do the variables you create with `np.loadtxt` have to do with the rest of your code? Do you want to separate each line of a single file into separate files?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi   

What im trying to do is to take the every line (24 lines in total) of each file (5 files in total) and save it to a new txt. So i will have at the end 24 new txt files with 5 lines. 

For example for the x_p2_40.txt i want to take the first line and save it to 1_p_40.txt, then i want to take again the first line of the x_p4_40.txt file and save it to 1_p_40.txt and so it goes for the remaining three files. And then the same for the 2nd line of x_p2_40.txt which i want to save to 2_p_40.txt, and so it goes for all lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have multiple files here, you could define their names in a list, and use a list comprehension to open file handles to them all:

```
input_files = ["x_p2_40.txt", "x_p4_40.txt", "x_p6_40.txt", "x_p8_40.txt", "x_p1_40.txt"]

file_handles = [open(f, "r") for f in input_files]
```

Since each of these file handles is an iterator that yields a single line every time you iterate over it, you could simply `zip()` all these file handles to iterate over them simultaneously. Also throw in an `enumerate()` to get the line numbers:

```
for line_num, files_lines in enumerate(zip(*file_handles), 1):
    out_file = f"{line_num}_p_40.txt"
    # Remove trailing whitespace on all lines, then add a newline
    files_lines = [f.rstrip() + "\n" for f in files_lines] 
    with open(out_file, "w") as of:
        of.writelines(files_lines)
```

With three files:

```
x_p2_40.txt:
2_1
2_2
2_3
2_4

x_p4_40.txt:
4_1
4_2
4_3
4_4

x_p6_40.txt:
6_1
6_2
6_3
6_4
```

I get the following output:

```
1_p_40.txt:
2_1
4_1
6_1

2_p_40.txt:
2_2
4_2
6_2

3_p_40.txt:
2_3
4_3
6_3

4_p_40.txt:
2_4
4_4
6_4
```

Finally, since we didn't use a context manager to open the original file handles, remember to close them after we're done:

```
for fh in file_handles:
    fh.close()
```

If you have files with an unequal number of lines and you want to create files for *all* lines, consider using `itertools.zip_longest()` instead of `zip()`

Answer (score 0):

In order to read each of your input files, you can store them in a list and iterate over it with a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). Then we add every line to a single list with the function [`extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?highlight=extend#array.array.extend) :

```
inputFiles = ["x_p2_40.txt", "x_p4_40.txt", "x_p6_40.txt", "x_p8_40.txt", "x_p1_40.txt"]
outputFile = "outputfile.txt"

lines = []
for filename in inputFiles:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines.extend(f.readlines())
        lines[-1] += '\n'
```

Finally you can write all the line to your output file :

```
with open(outputFile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(lines))
```